# using Selenium in Python to click on the right checkbox

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am very new to using selenium but I cannot find way around a very simple task.
I need to be able to click on the element that specifies bedrooms: 2.
I have used I don't know how many references by xpath, by id, by name, by class but selenium just won't find the element. I also have tried to browse the internet but could not find solutions that help me.

Here's the sanpshot

[image]
For instance: using

```
driver.find_element_by_id('agatha_bedrooms1588844814480_advancedSearch1').click()
```

This won't work. Selenium cannot find the element. It seems that this element is within another element but I don't understand how to access it.
Could you help me please?

Thanks a lot to you.

G

Comment: It's may be possible your `div` is in an `iframe`. Look higher up the html source for one.

Comment: Thank you. No there does not seem to be any: here's the direct link to the page. I have tried the iframe solution and it does not work. https://www.seloger.com/recherche-avancee.html?tri=initial&enterprise=0&idtypebien=2,1&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is inside of an iframe, do this:

```
# basically just select the iframe any way you want
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe")

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_id('agatha_bedrooms1588844814480_advancedSearch1').click()
```

edit:
I've found solution. Kinda ugly but works lol

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[name=bedrooms][value='2']")[0]
element.find_element_by_xpath("..").click()
```

Comment: Thank you. No there does not seem to be any: here's the direct link to the page. I have tried the iframe solution and it does not work. https://www.seloger.com/recherche-avancee.html?tri=initial&enterprise=0&idtypebien=2,1&div=2238&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4

Answer (score 0):

The ids seem to be dynamically generated, in which case you cannot rely on them. Try with this `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='bedrooms' and @value='2']/following::label").click()
```

Although it is generally good practice to work with waits. So something like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@name='bedrooms' and @value='2']/following::label"))).click()
```

Ensure to have these imports for the wait to work

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thank you. With this method I get the following error: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable. Although it clearly is a clickable element on the webpage.

Comment: Changed the xpath to get the label rather than the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, after multiple and multiple trials I could get around that way:

```
elemt = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@name='bedrooms']").find_element_by_xpath("//[@value='2']") 
idvar = elemt.get_attribute("id") 
elemt2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='" + idvar + "']") 
elemt2.click()
```

It seems that the checkbox was hidden under the label (?!) so that Selenium did not want to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath. hope its helps:

```
//*[@name='bedrooms']/following::*/*[text()='2']
```